# Using If with Days to caculate days between dates based on which column comes first with a date in the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get a formula so if columnA = a start date, and if column B has a date, it calculates the number of days, But, if it is blank it moves to column C and calculates the days, but if C is blank it goes to D...etc.

A different way to look at it might be is

- If B is blank go to C
- If B has date count days A to B and STOP
- If C is bank go to D
- IF C had date count days A to C and STOP

Example Table

[image: Example Table]

The closest I feel like I have come is:

`=IFS(ISBLANK([@Compliance]),If(ISBLANK([@Training]),IF(ISBLANK([@COMPLETED]),If(ISBLANK([@Cancel]),""),""),DAYS([@Cancel],[@Created]),DAYS([@COMPLETED],[@Created]),DAYS([@Training],[@Created]),DAYS([@Compliance],[@Created])))` 
Which looks like this:

I can see the issue. I have tried a few other ways. But I am just not getting it.

Any help to wire my brain around this would be great.

Comment: You could have tried this : `=IF(COUNTBLANK(B2:E2)<4,MINIFS(B2:E2,B2:E2,">0")-A2,"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, then this formula should work as per the given conditions:

[image]

---

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(B2:E2)<4,MINIFS(B2:E2,B2:E2,">0")-A2,"")
```

---

Or, Using `BYROW()` to spill all at once for the whole range, however dynamic array formulas don't work with `Structured References` hence you may need to use above one:

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(A2:E10,LAMBDA(x,
 LET(y, TAKE(x,,1), z, DROP(x,,1),
 IF(COUNTBLANK(z)<4,MINIFS(z,z,">0")-y,""))))
```

---

Although this is not needed as per the screenshot the dates are sorted in order from a-z, but if the dates are not sorted you wished to have days counted based on the logic you have stated then perhaps:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(B2:E2,MIN(IF(B2:E2<>"",SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(B2:E2)),"")))-A2,"")
```

---

And using `BYROW()` as well:

```
=BYROW(A2:E10,LAMBDA(x,
 LET(y, TAKE(x,,1),
 z, DROP(x,,1),
 IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(z,MIN(IF(z<>"",SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(z)),"")))-y,""))))
```

---

Comment: =IF(COUNTBLANK(B6:E6)<4,MINIFS(B6:E6,B6:E6,">0")-A6,"")   WORKED!
I am reading up on how it worked now.  Thank you. 

The "Byrow" approach is beyond me. 

However, as soon as I saw this work, I realized that I actually need to create a column in PowerQuery so it is done with the refresh of data as it is added.    This might be the most noob question ever, but do I just go ask the question again and tag it to power query or something?

Thank you all again. This was awesome.

Comment: @TravisWebb you are looking for a `Power Query` solution? then you should ask a new question instead before accepting the above answer by checking the tick mark beside it.

Comment: Thank you!  I also can't do the PQ idea now. The dang data isn't  there.